# How do I get the difference between an associative array and a regular array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, associative-array

Is it possible to get the difference of an associative array and a regular array in Javascript?

Ex.

```
array1 = [5, 1, 3];
array2 = [1 => 15, 2 => 20, 3 => 10, 4 => 5, 5 =>50 ];
```

The difference would be...

```
diff = [2 => 20, 4=> 5];
```

Comment: Your second array should be an object, not an array (JavaScript doesn't *have* associative arrays as such). And indeed, pasting the above into the JavaScript console in Chrome reports: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token >" Further: potential dupe, at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: Your second array isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean the second array should be like... array2[1] = 15?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the `diff` should deliver only those _values_ that are contained in array2, but not in array1. However, array2 has the values `15, 20, 10, 5, 50`, thus the diff would have to be `[15, 20, 10, 50]`, since 1 and 3 are only _keys_ of array2.
Kudos for messing up JS object notation with Perl hash notation, though, happens to me all of the time, when I'm doing both within a short stretch of time or switching back and forth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your question just had a small typo in your declaration of `array2`.  This is not a big deal.

Anyway, here is a bit of hack, but it gives you what you want:

```
array1 = [5, 1, 3];
array2 = {1: 15, 2: 20, 3: 10, 4: 5, 5: 50};

var result = {};
for (var i in array2) {
    if (array1.indexOf(+i) < 0) {
        result[i] = array2[i];
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/VjNHn/)

My hack is the `+i` in the `indexOf` call, because the properties of your "associative array" are strings, but your `array1` contains numbers.  The unary `+` produces a number from a string.  Kind of hackish but it is idiomatic an accepted JavaScript practice.

**ADDENDUM**

As RobG points out, `indexOf` is an ES5 method, so if your JavaScript engine is ES3 or below, you will need to implement `indexOf` on your own.  [An example of how to do this is at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Alternatively, you can just do the equivalent of `indexOf` by searching the array on your own.

​

Comment: And UAs without the ES5 *indexOf* method for Arrays (e.g. IE 8 and lower) will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks @RobG, added ES5 note to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your second array should be an object and isn't valid JavaScript, as the first two commenters said. Here it is in object form:

```
var object = { "1": 15, "2": 20, "3": 10, "4": 5, "5": 50 };
```

This function achieves your desired result:

```
function findDiff(arr, obj)
{
    var tempObj = clone(obj);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        var propId = arr[i];
        if (tempObj[propId] !== undefined)
            delete tempObj[propId];
    }
    return tempObj;
}
```

This function relies on a function called `clone`, which makes sure `obj` is copied to `tempObj` by value rather than reference. This prevents the passed object from being modified:

```
function clone(obj){
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
        return obj;

    var temp = obj.constructor(); // changed

    for(var key in obj)
        temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
    return temp;
}
```

Just call it like this:

```
var array = [5, 1, 3];
var object = { "1": 15, "2": 20, "3": 10, "4": 5, "5": 50 };

var diff = findDiff(array, object);
```

Comment: Note that the assignment of `tempObj = obj` effectively does nothing useful, the function returns the modified original object, not a copy. Also, the property name to be deleted should be checked before attempting to delete it (see [ES5 delete operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.1)) as it may throw an error in strict mode.

Comment: You're right, nice catch (especially on my shallow copy, I don't know how I missed that). Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to explain in detail what you expect the result of the operation to be.

One interpretation is to remove members from one array based on the values in another, so given:

```
array1 = [5, 1, 3];
array2 = [15, 20, 10, 5, 50 ];
```

You might have a function:

```
function diff(arr1, arr2) {
  // Copy arrays so don't affect originals
  var t1 = arr1.slice();
  var t2 = arr2.slice();

  // sort t1
  t1.sort();

  // Remove members of arr2 from highest indexes to lowest
  var i = t1.length;
  while (i--) {
    t2.splice(t1[i], 1);
  }
  return t2;
} 

 alert(diff(array1, array2));  // 15, 10, 50
```

Note that arrays are zero indexed and there is no 5th member in array2, so the removed values are 20 and 5 (i.e. members with index 1 and 3 respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be, to do a `JSON.stringify()` on your variable and check the leftmost or rightmost character of the resulting string. If it is `{` or `}`, you have an associative array / object, if `[` or `]`, it is an array. Which I imagine might be a bit costly, depending on the size of your array, but it would do the job.

*However...* since there is no such thing as a free lunch, and all animals come in pairs, this is only a reasonable solution, if you have used your variable consequently according to your original definition.
If you defined an object, like so: `obj = [1,2,3]` and then, at a later point, added a value such as `obj['w'] = 'ww'`, a `JSON.stringify(obj)` would only produce `[1,2,3]`, but if you addressed `obj['w']` again, you would still get `ww`, meaning that the value is not forgotten, they just don't mix. Internally, I would imagine, that javascript keeps two separate variable tables, one for objects and one for arrays, and whichever has been defined first, gets the nod when printed with stringify.

And to confuse things still more, if you define a variable as object first, but then add an array key, aka

```
obj = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33};
obj[4] = 44;
```

the new key is automatically cast as a string, thus yielding a result in stringify of

```
{"1":11, "2": 22, "3": 33, "4": 44}  //sans the \", for better readibility
```

Confusing as hell, but I guess that's the price you pay for a little anarchy and ease of use.